# Android List Adapter Sort by date

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I have a program that retrieves data from a database and displays it in a list adapter, But i want to sort the data by the planned date in Ascending order. Can anyone help

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> TimesheetList =  controller.getAllworkinstructions();


if(TimesheetList.size()!=0) {

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


        Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Id);
        String valId = Id.getText().toString();                   
        Intent  objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewCuttingtask.class);
        objIndent.putExtra("Id", valId); 
        startActivity(objIndent); 

        }

    }); 


    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Menu.this,TimesheetList, R.layout.list, 
        new String[] { "Id","weekcomm","jobid","taskid","planneddate","name","Priority"},    
        new int{R.id.Id,R.id.weekcomm,R.id.jobid,R.id.taskid,R.id.planneddate,R.id.name,R.id.priority}); 

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with adapters.

You should sort your collection depending on your needs then pass it to your adapter (or notify it if you already passed it to a ListView, for instance).

By sort, I mean:

- database query time sorting
- using Collection.sort(yourCollection, aComparator)

Answer (score 0):

I assume one of these Strings refers to date `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> TimesheetList` Just sort TimesheetList by date and give sorted list to array adapter